# Ожидание RecyclerView , пока не закончится поток

Tags: android, многопоточность, recyclerview

Вот мой код

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contracts, container, false);

            Log.d(TAG, "Start");
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();

    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);



    return view;



}

Handler handler = new Handler();
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void run() {
        String token = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("access_token");
        Log.d(TAG, token);
        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ResponseHandler GetResponse = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpGet http = new HttpGet("http://mysite/api/v1.3.0/contract/getlist?access_token="+token);

        try {

            String response = (String) hc.execute(http, GetResponse);
            Log.d(TAG, response);

            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray contracts = jobj.getJSONArray("contracts");
            String contract = contracts.getString(0);
            int l  = contracts.length();

                   for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
                       names[i] = names[i] + contracts.getString(i);
                       Log.d(TAG, names[i]);

                   }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();

    allItems.add(new ItemObject(names[1], "6"));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Мои обращения", "2"));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Ближайший офис", "3"));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Заказать звонок", "4"));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Позвонить в контактный центр", "5"));

    return allItems;
}
```

Мне необходимо что бы в cardview загрузилась информация из массива names. Но информация не успевает загрузиться, RecyclerView быстрее создается, чем поток заканчивается. Что посоветуете?

Comment: После заполнения данных делать `notifyDataSetChanged()` списку ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Применять адаптер `rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);` после выполнения всех действий.
2. Менять адаптер после выполнения всех действий `rView.swapAdapter(newAdapter, false);`
3. После изменения данных вызывать notifyDataSetChanged();

Выбирайте на свой вкус.

Comment: есть разница между 1 и 2  в данном случае?

Comment: есть, проще и быстрее использовать 1 случай